# Unable to set state in useEffect hook React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jwt, local-storage

I have a navbar in my project where I am displaying the name of the user currently logged in and also has a logout button.
When I try to login the page works fine and the jwt auth-token is stored in the local storage of the browser to maintain session. But after I have logged in, if I refresh the webpage then the jwt key is being cleared from the local storage. I even tried to put the state in the dependency array in useEffect but that doesn't work either because till I get the right user value I am logged out of the application.

The referenced code is as follows:

```
// part of navbar.js
const { User, getUser } = useContext(NoteContext);
const handleLogout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    // setUser("");
    navigate("/login");
  };

  useEffect(
    () => {
      getUser();
      if (User === "") {
        handleLogout();
      }
    },
    []
    // [User] // even this doesn't work either.
  );
```

```
// part of context
const [User, setUser] = useState("");
  const getUser = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`${host}/api/auth/getuser`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "auth-token": localStorage.getItem("token"),
      },
    });
    if (response.status === 200) {
      const json = await response.json();
      setUser(() => json.user.email);
    } else {
      setUser(() => "");
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`User` will not be updated until the next render, so it will not change from the initial value in that hook. Instead, you should make `getUser` return the user as well, then check based on that. Something like this should work:

```
  useEffect(
    async () => {
      const newUser = await getUser();
      if (newUser === "") {
        handleLogout();
      }
    },
    []
    // [User] // even this doesn't work either.
  );

  const getUser = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`${host}/api/auth/getuser`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "auth-token": localStorage.getItem("token"),
      },
    });
    if (response.status === 200) {
      const json = await response.json();
      setUser(() => json.user.email);
      return json.user.email;
    } else {
      setUser(() => "");
      return "";
    }
  };
```

Comment: Just an addition: the main reason is that `getUser()` is async and isn't guaranteed to have completed before the useEffect hook runs.

Comment: @JohnDetlefs Even if it weren't async, it would still not work. The variable won't update until the next render, so it'll never run with the updated user.

Comment: I need to make IIFE to do that else useEffect throws error with async functions.